# Laravel pausing scheduler when rate limit is hit

Tags: laravel

I'm working with an external API using Laravel however I'm having an issue hitting the rate limit. I have a list of users which need to be either created or updated on the platform. I want to do this every 2 hours so I'm using a scheduler to do it however if I was to have something like 100 users I would need to pause the current task for an hour before continuing. My question is would it be possible to pause the execution and continue or would my only option be stopping and rerunning?

Comment: or you could schedule you task every hour and take only 100 unprocessed users to process.